# При подключении шрифтов отображается только один шрифт

Tags: css, frontend, gulp, шрифты, sass

**Файл fonts.sass**

```
@font-face
font-family: 'ABC Monument Grotesk Mono'
src: url('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskMono-Regular.eot')
src: url('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskMono-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url:('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskMono-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
url:('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskMono-Regular.woff') format('woff')
font-weight: 400
font-style: normal
font-display: swap

@font-face
font-family: 'ABC Monument Grotesk Semi-Mono'
src: url('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskSemi-Mono-Regular.eot')
src: url('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskSemi-Mono-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url:('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskSemi-Mono-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
url:('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskSemi-Mono-Regular.woff') format('woff')
font-weight: 500
font-style: normal
font-display: swap

@font-face
font-family: 'ABC Whyte Medium'
src: url('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Medium.eot')
src: url('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url:('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
url:('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Medium.woff') format('woff')
font-weight: 500
font-style: normal
font-display: swap

@font-face
font-family: 'ABC Whyte Regular'
src: url('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Regular.eot')
src: url('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url:('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
url:('./fonts/ABCWhyte-Regular.woff') format('woff')
font-weight: 400
font-style: normal
font-display: swap
```

**Вот как это выглядит на сайте**
[image: шрифт на сайте]
**Использую препроцессор SASS и GULP**

Проверял пути/имена/табуляцию, всё указано верно. Причем заметил такую штуку, что даже когда я удалял шрифт, откуда-то вместо дефолтного Times New Roman был всё тот же Whyte шрифт.

Comment: А вы каким-нибудь элементам в стилях задали этот шрифт?

Comment: В font-family незачем вписывать Regular, Medium. Пишите просто ABC Whyte в обоих случаях, а толщину задаёте уже в стилях через font-weight - в вашем случае это - 400 и 500; А то вы задолбаетесь постоянно вписывать font-family: ABC Whyte Regular; и font-family: ABC Whyte Medium;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге перепробовав множество способов, сработал только один.

**Убрать все форматы кроме woff и написать их в одну строчку.**

```
@font-face
font-family: 'ABC Monument Grotesk Regular'
src: url('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskSemi-Mono-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./fonts/ABCMonumentGroteskSemi-Mono-Regular.woff') format('woff')
font-weight: 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить скобки и точки с запятой (Пример с документации на MDN)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "MyHelvetica";
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Bold"), local("HelveticaNeue-Bold"),
    url("MgOpenModernaBold.ttf");
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

UPD. (Подсмотрел у Йезена Томаса.)
Разрывы строк не поддерживаются в SASS, поэтому, чтобы создать `src` свойство со значениями, разделенными запятыми, вам нужно записать все значения в одну строку

`src:  url('fontname.woff') format('woff'), url('fontname.ttf') format('truetype'),` и т.д.